# Pandas sorting multindex and reset

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I'm trying to go through a dataframe with 2 index levels.
I previously removed entries from the dataframe, so often the second level is not ascending. But I want it to be.
What's a good way of resetting the second level index to a sorted list?

e.g.

```
a = [{'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3, 'D':4}]
b = [{'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3, 'D':4}, 
     {'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3, 'D':5},
     {'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3, 'D':4}]
c = [{'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3, 'D':4}]
df = pd.concat({10:pd.DataFrame(a), 20:pd.DataFrame(b), 30:pd.DataFrame(c)})
df.index.names = ['foo', 'bar']
```

So df would look like this:

```
         A  B  C  D
foo bar
10  0    1  2  3  4
20  0    1  2  3  4
    1    1  2  3  5
    2    1  2  3  4
30  0    1  2  3  4
```

Now, if I happen to remove all entries, where column 'D' >=4:

```
df[df['D']<=4]
```

we get something like this:

```
         A  B  C  D
foo bar
10  0    1  2  3  4
20  0    1  2  3  4
    2    1  2  3  4
30  0    1  2  3  4
```

I now would like to reassign a sorted 'bar' index for every 'foo' index.
It then should look like this:

```
         A  B  C  D
foo bar
10  0    1  2  3  4
20  0    1  2  3  4
    1    1  2  3  4
30  0    1  2  3  4
```

This *seems* easy enough, but I can't figure out a good way to reset the second index level dynamically. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df = df[df['D']<=4]  
df.reset_index('bar', drop=True, inplace=True)
df['bar'] = df.groupby(level='foo').cumcount() 
df.set_index('bar', inplace=True, append=True)
print (df)
         A  B  C  D
foo bar            
10  0    1  2  3  4
20  0    1  2  3  4
    1    1  2  3  4
30  0    1  2  3  4
```

Comment: Thank you for accepting. You can upvote too - click to small triangle above `1` above accepting mark. Thanks. Also if you find in `StackOverflow` some other helpful answers, dont forget upvote too. Nice day.